# Multiple Spring-boot applications running on one Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, spring-boot

Can I have two (or more) Spring-boot applications running on one Tomcat?

I have two applications packaged as `war` files and I would like to run them on one Tomcat server. However, when I deploy them, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: 
    Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.DataEndpointMBean@2361d8ee] with key 'dumpEndpoint'; 
    nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=dumpEndpoint
```

The default endpoints that every Spring-boot application registers (like /health etc.) clash. Is there some workaround for this or is not possible to achieve this setup?

Thank you for any responses!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Spring Boot Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html) says:

> If your application contains more than one Spring ApplicationContext you may find that names clash. To solve this problem you can set the **endpoints.jmx.uniqueNames** property to true so that MBean names are always unique.

```
endpoints.jmx.domain=myapp
endpoints.jmx.uniqueNames=true
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed this one.

Comment: I have  two spring boot application deployed on same tomcat  and both application have same datasource. I get InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx:name=dataSourceMBean,type=ConnectionPool    . I have already set   endpoints.jmx.domain=myapp
endpoints.jmx.uniqueNames=true. But I still get the error. Any suggestions

Comment: @Mukun were you able to figure this out?

Comment: I am running multiple  spring boot apps in tomcat. But all are connecting to different DB/Schema.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Maciej answer.  An alternative is to set the following

```
spring.application.name=my-app-name
spring.jmx.default-domain=my-app-name
```

Or for `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app-name
  jmx:
    default-domain: my-app-name
```

Worked for me on Spring boot `1.5.9.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jmx.default-domain=app-name
spring.jmx.unique-names=true
```