# Spring boot + multiple war files + tomcat fails to load webpage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Two spring boot applications are running on same tomcat, my configuration are as follows:

`application.properties`

**For first application**
spring.application.name=app1
spring.jmx.default-domain=app1

**For second application**
spring.application.name=app2
spring.jmx.default-domain=app2

*About two application*
**app1** : Web application + REST API
**app2** : Service (running in infinite loop) with **@PostConstruct**

First I think it was problem of **@PostConstruct** so I have tried following links:
[Other options for @postconstruct](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)
[Implementing interface as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring)

Then I came to read this question:
[Multiple spring-boot under same tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901936/multiple-spring-boot-applications-running-on-one-tomcat)

So I made changes to `application.properties` still my issue not resolved.

**Problem:**
When I deploy *app1* then *app2* it works totally fine (very first time), but restarting tomcat will start both application (log files containing data) normally ***but it fails to load webpage of*** ***app1*** it gives   **503 service unavailable**

Answer appericiated.

Comment: Any error traces in server.log file?

Comment: @DarkKnight No error in apache, tomcat and application log files, that's why not able to figure out problem

Comment: @iamrajshah - first of all, it's first time I am knowing about multiple spring boot apps in same servlet container. As far as I understood, when you restart it creates the html pages / resource files but overwrites with other app's data. Please try to change path of resource files in both apps (with different name and path) and try again.

Comment: @iamrajshah - also make sure the `jmx` port to connect tomcat is different in both apps (I guess it should be different for each apps).

Comment: @smilyface can you specify me the `jmx port` property? I haven't find anything like that

Comment: @iamrajshah - I mean to say AJP port. Sorry for the confusion. it is the port which connects the servlet container with the server. Here in your case it's tomcat. As I mentioned above, I am new to multiple boot apps in same container. jmx port will be there internally. We dont handle it manually. But in your case, I guess we may need to handle it manually. I have done multiple-tomcat-instances long before (which is only for traditional tomcat) where I manually mentioned start-up , shutdown and AJP ports independantly.