# While deploying more than one Spring Boot application in a single Tomcat server means showing exception. How to solve this?

Tags: linux, spring, apache, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot in my Java application, and to deployment used Tomcat 7. I was trying to deploy multiple Spring Boot projects in the same server it showing exceptions. But deploy one Spring Boot application and another one was Spring application means it's working.

The exception is:

```html
2016-01-22 08:05:18.301  INFO 16021 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2016-01-22 08:05:18.303  INFO 16021 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2016-01-22 08:05:18.312  INFO 16021 --- [ost-startStop-1] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/apns-0.1.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/asm-all-repackaged-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/bean-validator-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/class-model-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/config-types-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/core-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.10.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-api-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-config-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-locator-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-runlevel-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-utils-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hornetq-commons-2.4.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hornetq-core-client-2.4.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hornetq-jms-client-2.4.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hornetq-journal-2.4.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hornetq-native-2.4.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.5.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.4.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-bean-validation-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-client-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-guava-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-media-multipart-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-spring3-2.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jettison-1.2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jgroups-3.3.4.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/mimepull-1.9.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.5.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/netty-all-4.0.13.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.6.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.10.4.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-batch-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-hornetq-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jersey-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-undertow-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-bridge-2.3.0-b10.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-commons-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-context-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-security-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-starter-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-starter-oauth2-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-cloud-starter-security-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-crypto-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-jwt-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-social-core-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/tiger-types-1.4.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/undertow-core-1.1.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/undertow-servlet-1.1.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.7.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xnio-api-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xnio-nio-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/sunbox/WEB-INF/lib/xstream-1.4.2.jar]
2016-01-22 08:05:18.317  INFO 16021 --- [ost-startStop-1] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-01-22 08:05:18.324 ERROR 16021 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@5edb3f8d] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
 at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
 at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
 at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
 at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
 at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
 at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678)
 at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
 ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901936/multiple-spring-boot-applications-running-on-one-tomcat

Comment: @Sumit Already i tried this one, but its not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried setting different default domains, Property: spring.jmx.default-domain

Comment: @koe How do i set that one ?

Comment: in your application.properties or via "<Environment>" entry in your context.xml for your webapp in tomcat. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @koe I checked the same way, but its showing the same error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think what happens when you deploy multiple Spring Boot applications is those apps try to register to jmx on the same jvm using the same name.

1. Check this issue for the solution https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/118
2. Copy-paste from DavidBiesack's solution
   (regarding `application.properties` or `application.yaml`)

I was able to solve this by defining the following in my `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=my-app-name
spring.jmx.default-domain=my-app-name
```

Or for `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app-name
  jmx:
    default-domain: my-app-name
```

Comment: You should copy the relevant information into your answer for future reference, because links can go down, github issues can be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, we need to have two of the same application online during updates before cutting over sessions to maintain 100% uptime. In this case, you cannot just specify a unique name (unless you update it for each potential deployment). Instead, I disabled jmx with the following setting in my application.yml file for all profiles:

```
spring:
  jmx:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: I assume 90% or more apps don't use jmx, so why this is enabled by default is beyond me...

Answer (score -2):

I think the jmx doesn't allow 2 beans with the same objectName to be created. 
You have 2 options.

1. Turn off JMX and try to start it again.
2. Change the name of the bean `environmentManager`(and any other duplicated bean) on one of the applications you are putting in the same container