# Two Spring JUnit test classes: InstanceAlreadyExistsException when @TestPropertySource value differs

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have two identical test classes: ATest and BTest. Only the names are different. Here's ATest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"myProperty=true"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void aTest() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello");
    }
}
```

I run both of these classes at the same time, and they both pass. But if I open one of the two and I change the value of myProperty to false (now testA and testB have opposite values for myProperty), the second test will fail with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@444720b7] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:628)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:682)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:618)
    ... 41 more
```

This makes absolutely no sense. Can anyone understand what is wrong?

Comment: Looks like because of difference in property's value Spring Boot starts two contexts. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987502/while-deploying-more-then-one-spring-boot-application-in-a-single-tomcat-server You might need to pass different values for `spring.jmx.default-domain` property

Comment: This is it! I'll write the solution in an Answer post below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is, as @Ivan said in a comment, as follows:

When you run tests with different properties, Spring starts two different contexts (one for each property sets) in the same JVM. But the contexts are inside the same JMX domain name, and that cannot happen. This is explained in full details here: [While deploying more then one Spring boot application in a single tomcat server means showing exception. How to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987502/while-deploying-more-then-one-spring-boot-application-in-a-single-tomcat-server)

The workaround for this problem is to specify different JMX domain names for each test class. For example, look at the @TestPropertySource on this test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"mock.random-devices=false", "spring.application.name=BTest", "spring.jmx.default-domain=BTest"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BTest {
    @Test
    public void bTest() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello");
    }
}
```

And of course in the ATest class, the app and JMX domain names are ATest.

This makes both tests succeed.

Thanks @Ivan for your help.